# spring boot: StoredCredential (Permission denied)

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, spring-boot, tomcat8

Using spring boot, war package on ubuntu tomcat. The credential file is packaged in resources/credentials/gmail, but my mail service throws this error:

```
"/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/credentials/gmail/StoredCredential (Permission denied)"
```

how can I fix this error?

I installed tomcat8 with apt-get, I do believe that it created a tomcat8 user and group...does it have to do with user permissions for the folder?

edit:

```
2015-11-08 12:12:33.245 ERROR 12664 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration$Dynamic;
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean.onStartup(ServletRegistrationBean.java:189)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:221)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:84)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:205)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5170)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What happens if you start it with `java -jar myapplication.war`.  Thats the advantage of spring boot so you don't need to depend on the platform tomcat8 installation and configuration

Comment: added to edit:, application can't start with app.war. Though I usually run with war unzipped to ROOT folder so the credential file can be written/read? correct me if i'm wrong..

Comment: You cut of the important part of the stacktrace. `Unable to start embedded Tomcat`... and then? Maybe because of "Address is already in use"?

Answer (score 1):

with winscp, navigate to the credentials folder and apply (others) R W X permissions to folder + recursively. tomcat8 will now be able to access/edit the credentials file inside.